# Cannot draw with default blank grease pencil object - bug?

Tags: grease-pencil

In 2.93.5, in a default new scene (from File -> New -> General, not 2d animation), I add a new blank grease pencil object and select it. Then I switch to drawing mode, front view, ortho view, and just draw on the canvas. Nothing draws. Then change cursor to 'display cursor.' Note that at this stage Blender HAS added a default layer to the grease pencil object (as seen in the object properties panel). Add a new material to use, and sill nothing.

If I add a new layer to the GP object I can draw on that one correctly.

Evidently, this 'auto-added' layer is a bug in Blender, and is impossible to use as a layer. It caused me a bit of time to figure out what was going on.

If I start from scratch again and add a layer before drawing, it works OK.

Do other people see this same oddness?

Comment: Seems like it was a bug, but using an Blender 3.0 alpha the issue isn't present--the new empty grease pencil object contains a functional layer.

Comment: Thanks for respnding, Brandon. Glad to know it does not seem to be something I'm doing.